# How to remove every second byte in a pipe?

Tags: bash, pipe, byte

I have a bash pipe, e.g. `$ src_prog | dst_prog`.

What command can I insert into the pipe so that every second byte is silently discarded?

I want dst_prog to only receive only bytes 0,2,4,6...

P.S. This needs to work for all values of a byte, not just ASCII or UTF8.

Comment: You might want to look at [Is there a fast way to read alternate bytes in dd](https://stackoverflow.com/q/55836859/5291015)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Updated** another awk:

```
$ echo -ne abcdef\\n123456\\nåäö | 
LC_ALL=C awk -F "" '{
    for(i=1;i<=NF;i++)                # iterate all chars
        if(i%2!=p)                    # output every other char
            printf $i
    if(p=((p&&NF%2)||(!p&&!(NF%2))))  # xor                                     
        printf "\n"                   # handle newlines, all but the last
}'
```

Output:

```
ace
246��
```

Output piped to `hexdump -C`:

```
00000000  61 63 65 0a 32 34 36 c3  c3 c3 0a                 |ace.246....|
0000000b
```

It handles newlines but fails with the last newline (`echo -n` but see the end of the dump).

Or maybe you could use this little c program:

```
$ cat foo.c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(void)
{
  int c;
  int i=0;

  while((c=getchar()) != EOF) {
    if((i=!i)!=0)
      printf("%c",c);
  }
  exit(0);
}
```

Then:

```
$ gcc -Wall foo.c && echo -n 1234äö | ./a.out | hexdump -C
00000000  31 33 c3 c3                                       |13..|
00000004
```

Answer (score 1):

You could put each single byte into single line with `fold`, remove odd lines with `awk` and concat it back with `tr`:

```
echo abcdefgh12345678 | fold -b -w 1 |  awk 'NR%2==1' | tr -d "\n"
aceg1357
```

P.S. `-b` flag if for bytes (not chars), but it seems it only works with single byte text data (ASCII)

Comment: Sorry, I should have specified that it needs to work for arbitrary, binary, data.

Answer (score 1):

You could use Ruby:

```
$ cat a.out | wc -c
9456
$ cat a.out | ruby -ne '$_.each_char.with_index{|c,i| print c if i.even?}' | wc -c
4728
```

Same but dumping bytes instead of counting:

```
$ cat a.out | hexdump -Cn10
00000000  7f 45 4c 46 02 01 01 00  00 00         |.ELF......|
$ cat a.out | ruby -ne '$_.each_char.with_index{|c,i| print c if i.even?}' | hexdump -Cn10
00000000  7f 4c 02 01 00 00 00 00  02 3e         |.L.......>|
```